# Which ARM SoC are supported by Ubuntu/will be supported in future?

Tags: server, arm, ubuntu-tv

I want to build an ARM based home server and a HTPC and I want to know which ARM SoCs are currently supported by Ubuntu or will be supported in the (near) future. Will Nvidia Tegra 2/3 be supported?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at:

- [Ubuntu Wiki on ARM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM);
- [Ubuntu 11.10 ARM image for Toshiba AC100 Nvidia Tegra 2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TEGRA/AC100);
- [The past, present, and future of Ubuntu on ARM](http://lwn.net/Articles/475851/).